# Filreader with a string

Tags: string, reader

This is my code:

```
public static void NameLaden() throws IOException {
    File f = new File(path1);
    FileReader g;
    g = new FileReader(f);
    Name = g.read();                
    g.close();      
}
```

The answer is probably really simple. The only problem I have is that he wants a `int` instead of a `string` for `Name`. But `Name` has to be a `string` since its a word.

Comment: what program language?

Comment: Could you add up a few details like what project, platform, version, IDE, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this. Did not test it, but it should work, if name is on the first line of the file.

```
public static void NameLaden() throws IOException {
    File f = new File(path1);

    FileReader g = new FileReader(f);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(g);
    String Name = br.readLine();
    br.close();   
    g.close();      
}
```